# There is no specific function for the generic 'dde_solver'

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am attempting to use the DDE solver for `ex4p4p1.f90` available from [radford](http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/ffddes/Files.html) using the [Fortran90 source](http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/ffddes/index.html) `dde_solver_m_unix.f90`. I believe I should be able to simply download and compile with zero changes and yet I am getting the following error:

```
ex4p4p1.f90:107:8:

    SOL = DDE_SOLVER(NVAR,DDES,DELAYS,HISTORY,TSPAN=(/ 0D0,350D0 /))
         1
Error: There is no specific function for the generic ‘dde_solver’ at (1)
```

In order to completely (and simply) reproduce this, I have written a small script which will download, extract, and compile the source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

### Download and extract solver
dde_solver_url=http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/ffddes/dde_solver_m.zip
wget $dde_solver_url
unzip dde_solver_m.zip

### Download main routine
example_code_url=http://www.radford.edu/~thompson/ffddes/ex4p4p1.f90
wget $example_code_url

### Compile
gfortran dde_solver_m_unix.f90 ex4p4p1.f90
```

Since I believe these files are written to be 'drag and drop' examples, I believe it may be a problem with my environment or perhaps I am compiling incorrectly.

Are there problems with the way I am compiling? If not, what minimal changes can I make to (1) the driver code (`ex4p4p1.f90`) to get this to work or (less desirably) (2) the solver code (`dde_solver_m_unix.f90`)?

Comment: It would be much better to show us that code. It is likely wrong. I don't think that this is something changable by different way of compiling, unless there is some preprocessing somewhere or you are changing the default real or integer kind for just part of the code.

Comment: The fact that they need unix specifix source is suspicious. Fortran is normally quite portable.

Comment: And given there is no `IMPLICIT NONE` in the solver module I am not going to investigate further. If you want to know more, find the appropriate specific function and check all the arguments one by one. It may need to  `-freal-8` or something like that, but who knows.

Comment: FWIW, the only difference between the unix and non-unix solver source code is line endings; the code is identical. I had the same experience trying to build with gfortran so as a check, I tried building with the Intel compiler using `ifort -g -warn all -stand f95 -o ex4p4p1  dde_solver_m_unix.f90 ex4p4p1.f90`. This worked and threw one warning on an unused variable. This could be a compiler issue; you may need a more recent version of gforttran. I'd ask the original authors at SMU.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I have an updated version of the dde_solver code at https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/dde_solver.

Answer (score 0):

The INTERFACE blocks used during the definition of the DKL_* functions specify that arguments 2, 3 and 4 of DDES should be assumed shape arrays. However ex4p4p1 has DDES defined has having arguments 2, 3 and 4 as being arrays that are fixed at compile time. This causes some confusion with the Intel compiler, and might also be what's happening with gfortran.
Try using

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:) :: Y,DY
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:,:) :: Z
```

instead of

```
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(NEQN) :: Y,DY
DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(NEQN,NLAGS) :: Z
```

in the interface block for DDES. Good luck.

Comment: This should not be a problem on it's own. It is perfectly legal to pass a static array to an assumed shape argument. But the code is not written in a nice way. Also, arclight reports it is actually working with Intel. What kind of problem or confusion do you see with Intel?

Comment: If I don't make the above change, I get the following complaint from Intel Composer XE 2017: error #7062: The characteristics of dummy argument 2 of the associated actual procedure differ from the characteristics of dummy argument 2 of the dummy procedure.   [DDES]

Comment: And note that you can't just change the definition of an interface block! Have you run the code? This is a kind of change that should normally lead to a crash.

Comment: @VladimirF, I read this answer as saying that there is a dummy procedure with assumed shape arguments, but the actual procedure has explicit shape arrays.  If that is what is meant, perhaps this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30620604).

Comment: If this is also a problem with gfortran, then I can see why it might fail to resolve DDE_SOLVER.

Comment: @francescalus I have just checked the code and you are right. The fix suggested by Jerry is correct then, although I would see changing the procedures in the example to conform to the API as much more natural.

Comment: @francescalus The compiler message is the other question is much more helpful, points more directly at the issue but I suppose we can mark them as duplicates.

Comment: FWIW, I tested with an older version of ifort on linux; maybe later versions tightened up their interpretation of the code.

Comment: Agreed, @VladimirF, it takes some understanding to see these as a duplicate proper. It may need a bridging thing to clearly link the two questions.